# how to get arguments in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a button and when I click on that function I need to call a directive.
For this I have writern the following code.before creating directive there is a ng-change function.I have removed ng-change and kept directive as follows,

```
<button  upload-file="selectedDocumentName,loanFolderNumber" ><!-- ng-click="uploadFile(selectedDocumentName,FolderNumber)" -->
```

How can I take that arguments `selectedDocumentName,FolderNumber` in my directive.I have tried in the following way,but I am not getting the values.

**Directive:-**

```
app.directive('uploadFile',['documentService',function(documentService){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE', 
        scope: {
            selectedDocumentName: '=',
            FolderNumber: '=',
        },controller: function($scope){
            $scope.selectedDocumentName;
        },
        link : function($scope,element,attrs){

            element.on('click',function(e){
            })

        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<button upload-file obj="obj">A</button>

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


    myApp.directive('uploadFile', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE', 
            scope: {
                obj1: '='
            },controller: function($scope){
                $scope.obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.obj1))
                console.log($scope.obj2.selectedDocumentName);
                $scope.obj2.selectedDocumentName = "DEF";
                 console.log($scope.obj2.selectedDocumentName);
            },
            link : function($scope,element,attrs){

                element.on('click',function(e){
                })

            }
        }
    });


    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
       $scope.obj = {selectedDocumentName : "ABC",loanFolderNumber : "DEDF"};
    });
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHVD9/4715/)

Comment: what about this button `<button  upload-file="selectedDocumentName,loanFolderNumber" ><!-- ng-click="uploadFile(selectedDocumentName,FolderNumber)" -->`

Comment: I am telling you to change this button only to the button i suggested.

Comment: In your suggestion button is not there

Comment: The call is going but the values are not coming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172926/discussion-between-user9130953-and-nandita-arora-sharma).

Comment: Wait i will tell you its fix in 10-15 mins

Comment: Use $scope.obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.obj1)) to create a new copy of the old object. Now when you make changes in the new object, it wont effect the old one.

Comment: This is working only for button not for text boxes or links, can you please suggest

Comment: The click is working for me. See this http://jsfiddle.net/FHVD9/4716/   What is not working for you?